# How to control IdentityUser.Id column values?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

I want to control what is assigned to the primary key, or Id column of an Identity User. Basically, the users of my system are also users of another system (requirement) and I want to use the user id from the other system when creating that user's account on my system. Having them be the same would simplify a lot of things as opposed to needing to support both the user id from the other system and a different one from mine.

So far, I have changed the type of the Id from a string to a long, to match. When I create a user, however, the new user create fails because Id is null. That is, IdentityUser expects the Id column to be an Identity so it's auto populated by the database on insert. Basically, it's ignoring the value I set Id to before calling Create(user, password). I've tried overriding the Id property as

```
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public override long Id
    {
        get { return base.Id; }
        set { base.Id = value; }
    }
```

but get the following exception:

```
[NotSupportedException: Modifications to tables where a primary key column has property 'StoreGeneratedPattern' set to 'Computed' are not supported. Use 'Identity' pattern instead. Key column: 'Id'. Table: 'CodeFirstDatabaseSchema.ApplicationUser'.]
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateCompiler.BuildSetClauses(DbExpressionBinding target, PropagatorResult row, PropagatorResult originalRow, TableChangeProcessor processor, Boolean insertMode, Dictionary`2& outputIdentifiers, DbExpression& returning, Boolean& rowMustBeTouched) +2292
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateCompiler.BuildInsertCommand(PropagatorResult newRow, TableChangeProcessor processor) +204
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.TableChangeProcessor.CompileCommands(ChangeNode changeNode, UpdateCompiler compiler) +412
```

Which basically say's Id needs to be an Identity column.

So at this point I'm at a loss as what to try next. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After getting away from this for a short while, I came back and did a bit more research and solved this. Basically, I had to decorate the DatabaseGeneratedAttribute with None instead of Computed or Identity.

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
public override long Id
{
    get { return base.Id; }
    set { base.Id = value; }
}
```